# Convex Combination of pairs of points

Tags: consumer-theory, optimization, consumption

Is it appropriate/meaningful to write vector/points $(a,b) \le (c,d)$, where i would mean component wise each component is $\le$

- Specifically is my example below with reference to concavity meaningful.
- I ask because i know we can start to use $\succeq$ and be more specific about preference relations, invoking the notions of  non-satiation (monotonicity) etc.

For example in the context of wanting to demonstrate that a concave function implies a convex hyper graph, something like this...

$[λx_1 + (1- λ)x_2, λy_1 + (1- λ)y_2] \le [λx_1 + (1- λ)x_2, f(λx_1 + (1-λ)x_2)]$

- Where $y \le f(x)$ and $f$ is concave.

Comment: It is meaningful if you explain that is how you use the term (so be explicit about componentwise use).

Comment: Okay that's great, thank you!

Comment: There is a (small) ambiguity about ≥, because there is ≧. When they are distinguished, ≥ means "elementwise ≥, but at least one strict". This is rare, but I think, stating how you use ≥ would be helpful.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was wondering, thanks Kitsune!

Comment: In my experience, this notation is used is some context, for example when speaking of order theory, and I agree that must be specified. But I would avoid to use that notation in general analysis, where it is not  usual, the example about concavity looks a little bit strange to me.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Well it's definitely fine to do the proofs without writing in the way I did, so maybe I will stick to the more standard approach. And yes I had a whole question on Order Relations ins Math Stack, but people just aren't as helpful there hahah